# ASP.NET Membership to Identity or Azure AD

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

I am migrating a public website away from ASP.NET Membership. My plan so far has been to use ASP.NET Identity with Entity Framework and SQL provider. However before doing this work, I am considering other options including Azure Active Directory for authentication management. What are the pros and cons of using Azure AD compared to ASP.NET Identity?

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on your requirement .

Maintaining your own identity system has a higher degree of freedom ,you could adjust the identity system on the basis of detailed application requirements.

Azure AD is a multi-tenant cloud based directory and identity management service ,lets you focus on building your application by making it fast and simple to integrate with a world class identity management solution used by millions of organizations around the world ,if requirement is implementing Single SignOn( SSO) using on premises identity, Cloud only identity, Federation (or authentication) against Cloud SaaS applications,you can take advantage of AAD.   please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis) for introduction about Azure AD .